# Why aren't my overflow and display properties working in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have in my CSS this class:

```
.middleContent { overflow: hidden; display:inline-block; }
```

This **works** in IE but **not** in Firefox or Chrome so I wanted to do a sanity check here because I am not sure how to write this and might need direction.

To leave it working in IE, I left the above line:

```
.middleContent { overflow: hidden; display:inline-block; }
```

So for Firefox and Chrome, do I add the following lines like this:

**For Firefox:**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
     .middleContent { overflow: hidden; }
}
```

**For Chrome:**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .middleContent { overflow: hidden; }
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.
To Target Chrome :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 div{top:0;} 
}
```

To Target any firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
      .selector {
         color:lime;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Andre3wap but it's not working for me. I am not uploading it but working locally, could that be the issue or am I doing something wrong?  I am getting complaints from Dreamweaver of : @-moz-document is an unknown rule and for the chrome line that there is an unexpected token '}'.

Comment: Does anyone else advise as to why my css is not working for Chrome and Firefox as directed above. Here is the code I am useing `@-moz-document url-prefix() { .middleContent { overflow: hidden; } } 

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { .middleContent { overflow: hidden; } }`   Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @PaulSquillace can you set up a Fiddle with what you have ? I have a fiddle created and I tested it accross browser and the proper styles was applied: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxgbd5kt/